# Expected number of turns until something happens

Tags: probability

Let $p$ be the chance of success in a single trial. All trials are independent. For example a die roll.

I wanted to know the expected number of attempts until a success is achieved. I did $x = 1 + p \cdot 0 + (1-p) \cdot x$ which simplifies to $x = 1/p$.

Is this correct? Is there another way to arrive at this result?

Comment: It is correct, and by far the most short and elegant way. Keep on thinking in this line! I would start with $x=p.1+(1-p)(1+x)$. For another way look at [geometrical distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the trials are independent and the chance of success in 1 trial is $p,$ the chance that the first success occurs on the $n$th trial is the chance that $(n-1)$ failures are followed by a success, which is $$P_n=(1-p)^{n-1}p.$$ This event,which we can call  $E_n,$ is disjoint from $E_m$ for any $m\ne n.$ So if $p>0$ the expected value of the numbers of trials, up to & including the first success, is $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nP(E_n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nP_n =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n(1-p)^{n-1}p.$$ Since $(1-x)^{-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{-n}$ for $|x|<1,$ we have $(1-x)^{-2}=\frac {d}{dx} (1-x)^{-1}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nx^n$ for $|x|<1.$ Therefore for $p>0$ we have $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n(1-p)^np=(1-(1-p))^{-2}p=1/p.$$

Comment: Note that you should distinguish the cases of $p=0$ (which you have) and $p=1$ (which you haven't).

Comment: @barakmanos I think it is safe to assume that $0<p<1$ (else the problem is trivial).

Comment: @barakmanos Good point. But I suppose that the proposer, can figure those cases out.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ denote the number of attempts until success, then:

- $p=0 \implies P(X=n)=0$
- $p=1 \implies P(X)=\begin{cases}1&n=1\\0&n>1\end{cases}$
- $0<p<1 \implies P(X=n)=(1-p)^{n-1}\cdot p$

---

Therefore:

$
 E(X)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}n\cdot P(n)=
 \begin{cases}
  0 & p=0\\
  1 & p=1\\
  \frac1p & 0<p<1
 \end{cases}
$

Comment: How do you compute the summation for $nP(n)$ when $0 < p < 1$?

Comment: @user51819: Using the geometric series formula $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$, which is valid for $0<x<1$ (and also for $-1<x<0$, though less relevant for your question, since $0\leq p\leq1$).

Comment: @user51819: Note that I have used a "tweak" of that formula, since in your case, the series starts from $n=1$ and not from $n=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another method: Let $X$ be the number of trials until a success. Then $\mathbb P(X>0)=1$, and for each positive integer $n$ we have
$$\mathbb P(X>n) = \mathbb P(X>n\mid X>n-1)\mathbb P(X>n-1) = (1-p)\mathbb P(X>n-1).$$ Induction yields $\mathbb P(X>n)=(1-p)^n$, and hence
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[X] &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb P(X>n)\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (1-p)^n\\
&= \frac1p.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Formalization of your method.

Let $X$ denote the number of trials needed to reach first success and let $E$ denote the event that the first trial is successful. Then:

$$\mathbb EX=\mathbb E(X\mid E)\Pr(E)+\mathbb E(X\mid E^c)\Pr(E^c)$$

Evidently $\mathbb E(X\mid E)=1$.

If the first trial is not succesful then we start over with one failure in our pocket, that is $\mathbb E(X\mid E^c)=1+\mathbb EX$.

So we get:$$\mathbb EX=1p+(\mathbb E(X)+1)(1-p)=1+\mathbb EX(1-p)$$
leading to: $$\mathbb EX=\frac1{p}$$
No summation is needed whatsoever. The method is shorter and more elegant than the others.